# Target group constantly fails health check on port 80 and launches new instances when using dynamic port mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have an ECS cluster and an Application load balancer. I have setup dynamic port mapping for Amazon ECS following [aws's docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/).

The problem is that port 80 of my instance gets registered as a target in my target group which always fail (and it will because the container is exposed at the ephemeral port range 32768 - 65535:

[image]

Because of that, the Autoscaling group that I have constantly spun up new EC2 instances and terminates existing ones

[image]

Bellow are my Tarraform config file that creates the ALB, listener and target_group:

```
resource "aws_alb" "default" {
  name               = "${var.app_name}-${var.app_environment}-alb"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = true
  subnets         = var.loadbalancer_subnets
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "default" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.default.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.default.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "default" {
  name_prefix = "rushmo"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "instance"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "2"
    unhealthy_threshold = "5"
    interval            = "300"
    port                = "traffic-port"
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200,301,302"
  }

}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default" {
  name             = "${var.app_name}-${var.app_environment}-ASG"
  desired_capacity = 1
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  health_check_grace_period = 600 # 10 min
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.default.name
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1

  target_group_arns    = [aws_lb_target_group.default.arn]
  termination_policies = ["OldestInstance"]

  vpc_zone_identifier = var.application_subnets
  protect_from_scale_in = true
}
```

**Note**: If I manually deregister the target on port 80 from the Target group the problem with the constant termination and launching of new instances is solved but I don't understand what I have done wrong and why this port 80 shows up as a registered target and not only the ephemeral port range

Comment: Was this ever solved? I am hitting the same on a similar issue and cannot debug the connectivity

Comment: Hi Nick, yes. The below answer resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is due to:

```
health_check_type         = "ELB"
```

This makes ASG to use ALB's health checks on port 80 of your instances. However, since you are using ECS, the health checks should be only used for your containers, not the instances themself. Thus it should be:

```
health_check_type         = "EC2"
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin. That change actually solved the problem with the constant termination/launching of instances. However, I do still see 2 targets registered in my Target Group for both port 80 (always Unhealthy) and another one for the container (in this case 50131). Is this normal?

Comment: Thanks, I can try recreating my environment and see if that get's rid of the port 80 target.

Comment: I forgot to report back that this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, did you ever determine if it was normal to see unhealthy on port 80 with healthy container ports registered?

Comment: @Brett I did not spend more time digging to the honest. Once I got it sorted by applying the suggested solution in this answer I did not spend additional time researching.